# Invalid literal for value with base 10

Tags: python, database, discord

I am making a discord.py bot and following the tutorial this is my code -

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from replit import db

client = discord.Client()
intents = discord.Intents.all()

#database func
def update_encouragement(encouraging_message):
  if "encouragements" in db.keys():
    encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    encouragements.append(encouraging_message)
    db["encouragements"] = encouragements
  else:
    db["encouragements"] = [encouraging_message]

def delete_encouragements(index):
  encouragements = db["encouragements"]
  if len(encouragements) > index:
    del encouragements[index]
    db ["encouragements"] = encouragements

#api requests
def get_quote():
    response = requests.get("http://zenquotes.io/api/random")
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    quote = json_data[0]['q'] + "\n -" + json_data[0]['a']
    return quote

#user-made quotes ----
sad_words = ["sad","unhappy","bad","miserable","depressed"]
starter_encouragement = [
  "You can do it!",
  "Hang in there!",
  "Its okay to feel sad",
  "Tommorow is a mystery, Today is a gift."
]

#clients and events-----
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('{0.user}'.format(client) + ' has successfully logged in.')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    msg = message.content
    if msg.startswith('.ltt help'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Linus Tech Tips Commands", description="Prefix - `.ltt` | Commands!", color=0x00ff00)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Help", value="Type `.ltt help` to get help on commands!", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Inspire", value="`ltt inspire` to get inspirational quotes!", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)

    if msg.startswith('.ltt inspire'):
        quote = get_quote()
        await message.channel.send(quote)
    options = starter_encouragement
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      #options = options.append(db["encouragements"])
      options.extend(db["encouragements"][:])

    if any(word in msg for word in sad_words):
      await message.channel.send(random.choice(starter_encouragement))
    
    if msg.startswith(".ltt new"):
      encouraging_message = msg.split(".ltt new ",1) [1]
      update_encouragement(encouraging_message)
      await message.channel.send("New encouraging message added")
    
    if msg.startswith(".ltt del"):
      encouragements = []
      if "encouragements" in db.keys():
        index = int(msg.split('.ltt del',1)[1])
        delete_encouragements(index)
        encouragements = db["encouragements"]
      await message.channel.send(encouragements)

async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Welcome to Linus Tech Tips, check out the merch at https://lttstore.com')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

After running and executing the `.ltt del` command, i get the following error -
[image]

Even after searching a lot i have found no solutions, the solutions saying add float to int give me this error -

```
index = int(float(msg.split('.ltt del',1)[1])) #added
```

[image]

**What happens when i execute it?**
The code is supposed to delete "encouragements" which is a string value assigned to a discord message when you type `.ltt new`. But, it doesnt delete it, and sometimes might say `ObservedList(value=[])` while in the tutorial it says `["Added Encourage message 1", "Added Encourage message 2"]` in which `Added Encourage message 1` is the message that is stored in the database.

Note: Im using replit
Another note: dont close the question saying its duplicate cause none of the other solutions work.

Comment: Break it down into steps and log each step to make sure the value is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the msg doesn't contain commas, spaces, or characters. (It should only contain int or float)

It can be understood by the below example :-

```py
msg = ".ltt del 92.091"  #Make sure that Your msg/command value should be in this format
print(int(float(msg.split('.ltt del',1)[1])))
```

Output will be :-

```
92
```

Comment: Nope, it doesnt work. It still returns the error: **ValueError: could not convert string to float: ` `**. Using .ltt del 2.0 or any other variable with float returns the number in console and returns: **if len(encouragements) > index:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'**

Comment: Are you are using `.ltt del 3.92` like command ??

Comment: yes, i did use the above mentioned format

Comment: It should work as same of mine codes are working in compilers....